# Using awk to select rows with a specific value in column greater than x

Tags: awk

I tried to use `awk` to select all rows with a value greater than 98 in the third column. In the output, only lines between 98 - 98.99... were selected and lines with a value more than 98.99 not.

I would like to extract all lines with a value greater than 98 including 99, 100 and so on.

Here my code and my input format:

`for i in *input.file; do awk '$3>98' $i >{i/input./output.}; done`

```
A   chr11   98.80   83  1   0   2   84

B   chr7    95.45   22  1   0   40  61

C   chr7    88.89   27  0   1   46  72

D   chr6    100.00  20  0   0   1   20
```

Expected Output

```
A   chr11   98.80   83  1   0   2   84

D   chr6    100.00  20  0   0   1   20
```

Comment: No, no... simply `awk '$3 > 98' *input.file` (which will use the default print to output)

Comment: 98.01, 98.23, 98.45, ... 98.99

Comment: Yes, you do it all with `awk`. No shell loop. Just `awk '$3 > 98' *input.file` Is it redirecting to `output.file` where you are confused?

Comment: I think `>{i/input./output.}` is missing a `$`

Comment: `awk '$3 > 98' *input.file` didnt work, i got the same output :/

Comment: yeah thats true (i forgot to copy it), but it won't fix my issue

Comment: if i select `awk '$3 > 99 input.file` i get no hits, wether there are lines with values bigger than 99

Comment: the issue is, that `awk`dont recognize 100.00 its bigger than the other values.

Comment: Ok. For the part of input file you pasted, doing `$3>98` "works" for me - the lines with `98.80` and `100.00` show up. Would you be able to post some more of the input file?  Create an [MCVE] so that others can get the same problem as you? Maybe add the output `awk --version`? Also maybe there are unprintable characters, maybe `head -n10 inputfile | hexdump -C` will reveal something?

Comment: I suspect you're in a locale that uses `,` as the decimal point but your data uses `.` and so awk is treating your input as strings rather than numbers. Set your locale using `LC_ALL=C awk 'script' file` and see how that goes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, if you have a series of files, `*input.file` and you want to select those lines where `$3 > 98` and then write the values to the same prefix, but with `output.file` as the rest of the filename, you can use:

```
awk '$3 > 98 {
    match (FILENAME,/input.file$/)
    print $0 > substr(FILENAME,1,RSTART-1) "output.file"
}' *input.file
```

Which uses `match` to find the index where `input.file` begins and then uses `substr` to get the part of the filename before that and appends `"output.file"` to the substring for the final output filename.

`match()` sets the `RSTART` value to the index where `input.file` begins in the current filename which is then used by `substr` truncate the current filename at that index. See [GNU awk String Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#String-Functions) for complete details.

For exmaple, if you had input files:

```
$ ls -1 *input.file
v1input.file
v2input.file
```

Both with your example content:

```
$ cat v1input.file
A chr11 98.80 83 1 0 2 84

B chr7 95.45 22 1 0 40 61

C chr7 88.89 27 0 1 46 72

D chr6 100.00 20 0 0 1 20
```

Running the `awk` command above would results in two output files:

```
$ ls -1 *output.file
v1output.file
v2output.file
```

Containing the records where the third-field was greater than `98`:

```
$ cat v1output.file
A chr11 98.80 83 1 0 2 84
D chr6 100.00 20 0 0 1 20
```

Comment: `match (FILENAME,/input.file$/)` and `substr(FILENAME,1,RSTART-1) "output.file"` are being done once per output line for every file, they only need to be done once per output (or input would be OK) file total for efficiency. Not closing the output files as you go means your awk will fail with a "too many open files" error after creating a doczen or so output files unless you're using GNU awk. Input/output redirection to/from an unparenthesized expression is undefined behavior per POSIX so it'll only work in some awks.

Comment: So do this instead: `awk 'FNR==1{ close(out); match(FILENAME,/input\.file$/); out=substr(FILENAME,1,RSTART-1) "output.file" } $3 > 98{ print > out }' *input.file` for efficiency and portability to all awks.